# Customizar headers con IHttpActionResult?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Actualmente tengo un método que retorna una lista de ciudades, el método lo tengo de la siguiente forma:

```
[ResponseType(typeof(List<Cities>))]
public IHttpActionResult GetSourceCities(int idPais)
{
    try
    {
        var cities = GetCities(idPais);
        return cities == null ? Ok(new List<Cities>()): Ok(cities);
    }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Write(ex.message);
            return NotFound();
        }
    }
```

Quiero implementarle cache para que acceda a la lista de ciudades de forma rápida y eficiente. Ahora bien, para hacerlo fácilmente, cambio el tipo de respuesta, pasa de ser un IHttpActionResult a HttpResponseMessage de tal forma que pueda agregarle el atributo de caché en el header.

```
[ResponseType(typeof(List<Cities>))]
public HttpResponseMessage GetSourceCities(int idPais)
{
    try
    {
        var cities = GetCities(idPais);
        //return cities == null ? Ok(new List<Cities>()): Ok(cities);
        var httpResponseMessage = Request.CreateResponse<List<Cities>>(HttpStatusCode.OK, cities); 
        httpResponseMessage.Headers.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue() 
            { 
                MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15) 
            };
        return httpResponseMessage;

    }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Write(ex.message);
            //return NotFound();
            var httpResponseMessage = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            return httpResponseMessage;
        }
    }
```

Ahora la cuestión es: No quiero usar HttpResponseMessage, cómo customizar el IHttpActionResult para implementarle caché ?

Answer (score 1):

Lo que podrías hacer es crear un [`ActionFilter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.http.filters.actionfilterattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) que añada los encabezados de cache a la respuesta

La implementación del filtro sería la siguiente:

```
public class CacheControlAttribute : System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public int MaxAge { get; set; }

    public CacheControlAttribute()
    {
        MaxAge = 3600;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        context.Response.Headers.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue()
        {
            Public = true,
            MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(MaxAge)
        };

        base.OnActionExecuted(context);
    }
}
```

Tu acción basada en `IHttpActionResult` quedaría así:

```
[ResponseType(typeof(List<Cities>))]
[CacheControl(MaxAge = 900)]
public IHttpActionResult GetSourceCities(int idPais)
{
    try
    {
        var cities = GetCities(idPais);
        return cities == null ? Ok(new List<Cities>()): Ok(cities);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Write(ex.message);
        return NotFound();
    }
}
```

Comment: Me gusta la respuesta, válida. incluso puedo implementarla de forma genérica para que todos mis controladores la usen. Gracias, sin embargo si quisiera salir de la duda haciéndolo directamente customizando el IHttpActionResult. Creando una nueva clase heredando de IHttpActionResult, pero no hallo cómo.

Comment: Hola @Makitodev, igual te ayuda [esta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21487980/1724791) respuesta de S.O en inglés